# Not catching exceptions even though it is inside try catch?

Tags: vb.net

I am deleting a row inside a DataGridView and when there is no more row this pops up.

```
    Private Sub materialsGridView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles materialsGridView.SelectionChanged
        Try
            materialSelectedindex = materialsGridView.CurrentRow.Index
        Catch ex As Exception
            materialSelectedindex = -1
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub delRowBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles delRowBtn.Click
        If (materialSelectedindex = -1) Then
            MsgBox("Please select a row")
            Return
        End If
        materialsGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(materialSelectedindex)
    End Sub
```

Here is an image
[image]

Why is it not catching even though it is inside a try catch?

Comment: Don't post code as only a picture. I want to reproduce your code in my answer and now I have to type it from scratch instead of just copying the text that you should have posted. The screenshot adds value in your case but ALWAYS post code as text first, then add a picture if appropriate.

Comment: This is an example of building exceptions into your logic, which is not what they are meant for. An exception is *exception*al, i.e. outside the rules of your logic. Also the question title is misleading once we found out that the actual problem is your logic is not comprehensive enough. The accepted answer provides a specific solution to a specific instance of a general problem you should try to avoid creating in your future development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Exception Assistant window. See how the box is checked that says *"Break when this exception type is thrown"*? If you don't want the debugger to break when that exception type is thrown, uncheck that box. That is only happening because you're running in the debugger. If you run the application without debugging, which you can do either directly or using the VS toolbar or pressing Ctrl+F5, then the exception will be caught.

By the way, it's generally bad practice to catch the base `Exception` type. You should catch only the specific exceptions that you reasonably believe could be thrown. Otherwise, you might be allowing a situation that you didn't count on and which might end up causing data corruption or the like.

You should also generally avoid exceptions being thrown in the first place, by validating the data you intend to use. In your case, you should check whether `CurrentRow` is `Nothing` first and then only use it if it's not. You could do this:

```vb
materialSelectedIndex = If(materialsGridView.CurrentRow Is Nothing,
                           1,
                           materialsGridView.CurrentRow.Index)
```

or you could do this:

```vb
materialSelectedIndex = If(materialsGridView.CurrentRow?.Index, 1)
```

The first option is basically an `If...Then...Else` while the second option uses the first value unless it's `Nothing`, in which case it uses the second value. The `?.` operator will stop evaluation of the expression if what precedes it is `Nothing`, otherwise it behaves like a regular `.` operator.